# Using Django, how I can achieve this in a single query?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, timedelta, django-aggregation

I have the following model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    # ... other fields omitted
    active_at = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = models.DurationField()
```

Given `now = datetime.now()`, I'd like to retrieve all records for which `now` is between `active_at` and `active_at + duration`.

I'm using Django 1.8. Here are the [DurationField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#durationfield).

Comment: Have you looked at [F objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the documentation, arithmetic with a `DurationField` will not always work as expected in databases other than PostgreSQL. I don't know to which extend this works or doesn't work in other databases, so you'll have to try it yourself.

If that works, you can use the following query:

```
from django.db.models import F

active_tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(active_at__lte=now, 
                                       active_at__gt=now-F('duration'))
```

The `F` object refers to a field in the database, `duration` in this case.